# Java Game: Shooting multiple players at same time

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm working on a game where players can shoot bullets. I am iterating through list of active players in the game, and shooting at players if they are near. It works mostly except for a case when two or more players are shooting at each other at the same time.

**Issue:**

When two players shoot at each other (same amount of bullets at same time), one dies but other still stays alive.

**Result:**

Both players should die at the same time.

How would I implement this case where both players should die?

I think it has to deal with one of the for loop. Since the first player in the list will shoot first the second player will reach maxDamage first, however I want them to reach maxDamage at the same time.

How the game works:

The animations happen in a single turn which counts down and executes the moves placed.

There are 4 move slots for every turn

```
            
            for (Player p : listRegisteredPlayers()) {
                if (!p.isDamageMaxed() && !p.isSunk()) {
    
                    // Apply damages if they collided with anyone
                    damagePlayers(leftShoots, p, Direction.LEFT, slot);
                    damagePlayers(rightShoots, p, Direction.RIGHT, slot);
                }

                if (p.isDamageMaxed() && !p.isSunk()) {
                    p.setSunk(slot);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Store the damage in every player. After all shots were shot, you evaluate the damage and then the ones that got too much damage, are killed

Comment: It sounds like there's an ordering/timing issue here. It's easy to help you beyond that due to the limited amount of code you've posted

Comment: @ControlAltDel I tried to make it as simple as possible without having to paste a bunch of code that may not make any sense. I narrowed it down to one single for loop that I thought was causing the issue. I've updated post with the entire method.

Comment: It looks like this line, `if (!p.getVessel().isDamageMaxed() && !p.isSunk()) {` is not going to allow a player to shoot left or right?

Comment: @matt Each vessel should sink on the specific slot they got maxed on, so when they get maxed they shouldn't should anymore after that. But if two players shoot each other at same time they should both die at the same turn, but its not currently working like that. If I remove that line, the other player sinks on the next slot, which isn't correct

Comment: I don't completely follow. You'll have to make more complete example. That specific loop seems asymmetric, in that a player that received max damage would not perform an action they would have if they were earlier in the loop.

Comment: @matt Okay, its based off the game Puzzle Pirates, the puzzle battle navigation. Where you are battle a ship, each ship has four slots as in the picture I supplied. Each ship can place 4 moves or 4 cannons on either side. So in my example both ships are firing cannons on each slot, where they both should have the same exact damage. Whenever a ship reaches max damage it should sink (on whichever slot the max damaged occured on, eg. slot 2). Since both ships shoot same exact number of cannons, giving same damage they should sink on the exact same slot. However, 2nd ship sinks on the next slot

Comment: In *that* conditional block you're applying damage. Player 1 applies damage to player 2. Player 2 gets skipped and does not apply damage to player 1 because they are at max damage. Without a minimal reproducible example *I* cannot deduce more. Maybe somebody else can figure it out though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you describe clearly means that if someone is dead, then he no longer can shoot. Now, player1 shoots on player2 and player2 shoots on player1. Now, this seems to happen in your case:

> player1 shoots player2
>
> player2 dies
>
> player2 does not shoot because
> he's dead

The solution seems to be to separate shooting from damage. You need to implement a loop where the shooting happens, but the players do not die yet. You just compute their damage and reduce that from their life, but they should be still alive at the end of the loop. Then, in a next loop evaluate the health of players and ensure that whoever should die dies.

If you need more details, then you will need to provide more details.

Comment: Yes, thats the general census I got from the code. But keep in mind, vessels should sink on their specific slot that they received max damage on. After they sink they should not be allowed to shoot. If I removed ```if (!p.getVessel().isDamageMaxed() && !p.isSunk()) {``` they both sink, but one of the vessels sink on the next slot, which isn't correct it. They should both be the same because they recieved same amount of damage

Comment: @dree you are right, but that's a next problem. Your events therefore need to happen in this order: 1. Shooting & Damaging loop 2. Dying loop 3. Moving loop